# How to get new entered value in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox in which I render some value the user can change. 
If user does, then I have to show a popup and tell him that *The new text you entered in textbox is this...*

If he clicks <kbd>OK</kbd> then I will submit that to DB. 
How to do that in JavaScript?

Suppose default value of textbox is

```
What,are,you,doing
```

and user enters this

```
What,are,you,doing,james
```

in this case user enters only `james`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery

```
oldVal = $('#textBoxID').val();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
       alert('You Entered: ' + $('#textBoxID').val().replace(oldVal, ''));

       // Submit form

       window.oldVal = $('#textBoxID').val();          
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="textBoxID">What,are,you,doing</textarea>
<button id="submit">OK</button>
```

example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyvbs/3/)